# How to fetch the logical name of a NIC card given the ip address associated with it ?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, networking, ifconfig

I am working on a shell script which needs to know the logical name (eth0, eth1, etc) associated with a given ip. The current procedure I am employing is to parse the output of ifconfig using filters and getting the NIC card associated with a given IP. I was wondering if there exists a simpler way or a direct pipelined linux command to get the above mentioned detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip=192.168.1.10
iface=$(ip addr | grep $ip | awk '{print $NF}')
echo "Iface is: ${iface}"
```

Comment: Brilliant... Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me the significance of $NF in the awk fliter ? That was one part I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @csurfer Thanks for accepting this answer. `NF` is the number of fields in the current record. `$NF` points to the value of the last field. See `man awk`. you could also print: `$7`.

Comment: So $NF acts something like cut -d " " -f <last column then ?

Comment: NF is a variable pointing to the total number of fields. `cut` does not have a equivalent feature. Run: `echo 'one two three' | awk '{print NF,$NF}'` to see the difference between `NF` and `$NF`